# Downloaded mp3 only plays for about 2 minutes. Is there a setting I have to change?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, audio, google, mp3

I've downloaded several mp3's so I can listen to them on my Samsung Galaxy S3. When I play them either through Google Play Music or Sound Player, I hear about 2 minutes of audio then it stops playing. I've attempted this with multiple mp3's. Is there a setting I need to change?

Comment: What do you mean "stops playing"? Does the app close without notice? Force close? MP3 file gets deleted suddenly?

Comment: Does this happen if you put the device to sleep? I had a similar issue but related to sleep and music player

Comment: @aureljared The app does not close. It appears that after a few minutes of playing, the scroll bar that tells you how much time is left scrolls all the way to the end.

Comment: @Firelord It may happen when the device locks.